# Git adding multiple upstream servers and tracking their respective branches

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a git repo that others have forked from me. I'd like to track the master branch from one of these repos into a branch named `feature/foo` on my local repository. Here's what I did  so far:

`git remote add johnny git@github.com:made_up_johnny/johnny.git`

Then, I tried creating a local branch after adding the upstream server `johnny`
:

`git branch --set-upstream feature/foo johnny/master`

At the end of the day, I get this:

`fatal: Not a valid object name: 'johnny/master'.`

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I just want to have multiple remote servers I can pull in features from for review. In this case I tried to add a remote upstream server aliased to `johnny` with a full URL to the github repo. then I tried to set a remote tracking branch and got the fatal error.

What's the right way of going about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not only to add a remote, but also fetch it:

```
git fetch johnny
```

Comment: that did it, need to go read more up on fetch. thanks Charles. I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as SO allows me to.